# Plotting multiple graphs in one page using loop

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am trying to plot multiple graphs on the same page. It works fine when I write the code one by one like this:

```
old.par <- par(mfrow = c(3,4))
plot(na.omit(AUS.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "AUS.Yield")
plot(na.omit(BRA.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "BRA.Yield")
plot(na.omit(CAN.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "CAN.Yield")
plot(na.omit(CHI.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "CHI.Yield")
plot(na.omit(GER.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "GER.Yield")
plot(na.omit(JAP.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "JAP.Yield")
plot(na.omit(SOA.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "SOA.Yield")
plot(na.omit(SWI.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "SWI.Yield")
plot(na.omit(UK.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "UK.Yield")
plot(na.omit(US.Yield), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "US.Yield")
```

But it does not work when I try to use a `for` loop e.g.:

```
## names(log_return[2:11]) will give me all those AUS.Yield, BRA.Yield etc as they are the column names of dataframe log_return

for (i in names(log_return[2:11]){
    plot(na.omit(i), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "i")
}
```

Also, I have generated 10 time series by using:

```
for (i in 2:length(log_return)){
  assign(names(log_return[i]),xts(log_return[i],log_return$Date))
}
```

so I got 10 time series that names: AUS.Yield, BRA.Yield.... etc.

Just wondering where went wrong.... 
Here is the error message:

```
 Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
```

I am thinking maybe I got so many NAs in my dataframe? But I have used the `na.omit` already.

Here is a small section of the datafram log_retrun;

```
      Date       AUS.Yield   BRA.Yield    CAN.Yield    CHI.Yield    GER.Yield   JAP.Yield
1 2008-01-01           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA        NA
2 2008-01-02           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA        NA
3 2008-01-03 -0.033047602 -0.01239795  0.003828977 -0.017857617 -0.031966192        NA
4 2008-01-04 -0.003922215  0.00198792 -0.008443187  0.006734032 -0.006984895        NA
5 2008-01-05           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA        NA
6 2008-01-06           NA          NA           NA           NA           NA        NA
```

The JAP.Yield may look all NAs but there are values after a several lines.

Thank you in advance for any help and suggestion!! T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create the `xts` objects persistently. Note the modification of the use of your `names()` function in the `for()` specification as well:

```
for (i in names(log_return)[2:11]){
    plot(na.omit(xts(log_return[[i]],log_return$Date)), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = i)
}
```

Or, as @SpacedMan mentions, you can use `get()` to reference the variables by name here as well if you do want the `xts` objects in memory:

```
for (i in names(log_return)[2:11]){
    plot(na.omit(get(i)), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem is solved now. I think I need more readings on the basics otherwise I will mess up again on those strings and names things.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a thing is a different thing from the thing itself.

The string "foo" and the object `foo` are different things. If you `plot("foo")` it tries to plot the string "foo". If you `plot(foo)` then you plot the object called `foo`.

So, what are you doing:

```
for (i in names(log_return[2:11]){
    plot(na.omit(i), xlab = "Date", ylab = "log_return", main = "i")
}
```

`names(something)` returns the names as strings. So you are doing `plot("AUS.yield")`, which is plotting the string and not the thing.

Solutions: best is to NOT make things with names using `assign`. Instead create a list with named objects. Then you can do something like `name="AUS.yield";data[[name]]` to get the data from a name in a string.

worst solution is to use `get(name)`, which tries to get the thing with the given name (in your case something like `plot(get(i))` should do it. This is the "worst" solution because its a fiddle to undo the mistake you originally made, of creating lots of objects by name when you should have structured them in a list.